# App rejection reason in AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've created app that can play audio online from vk.com social network. It can also download files to device BUT it doesn't share downloaded files with iTunes on PC or Mac. It just downloads files for listening them without internet connection. Vk.com licence agreement doesn't restrict this feature.
Apple has rejected my app with reason `22.4: Apps that enable illegal file sharing will be rejected`

So I need to remove this feature to make my app Approved? What do you think?

Comment: I guess, it is a bad idea to make any connection between your application and any file sharing website. no matter, it just downloads a file or just streaming a file from that servers the Apple will rejects automatically because of _there is connection_.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia:

> One distinction of VK is its integration with torrent filesharing technology which allows users to share larger files.

So, alas, my guess is that a combination of "Russian" and "torrents" is probably a double whammy against you. Unfair, perhaps.

Comment: No, there is no torrent filesharing. All links are direct to file server.

Comment: Timur, I'd say you can juggle this about any way you want but my feeling would be that apple simply objects to this app in its entirety not a certain aspect of it.

Comment: So what can you advice to solve this problem? Do I need to remove download feature? Then app will only work when there is internet connection

Comment: We're not Apple, so can't tell you exactly what to do. Removing the file downloading feature is likely a good start, though. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to include the (vk.com) link by default. Let users input the link instead, like any url in the Safari (as Apple cannot block people visiting a porn site through the browser).

Comment: My app uses vk.com API. It's not browser app. And there are a lot of apps with this type